# Gaussian fit not taking into account negative part of the peak

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, spectrum

As you guys can see in the below picture, I am doing a gaussian fit on the spectrum that has some of it in the negative part of the y-axis:

[image]

This is how I am doing the fit:

```
def Gauss(velo_peak, a, mu0, sigma):
         res = a * np.exp(-(velo_peak - mu0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
         return res
mu0 = sum(velo_peak * spec_peak) / sum(spec_peak)
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(spec_peak * (velo_peak - mu0)**2) / sum(spec_peak))
peak = max(spec_peak) 
p0 = [peak, mu0, sigma]   
popt,pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, velo_peak, spec_peak, p0, maxfev=100000)
```

my main goal is to find the value of the peak of the spectrum, but it is clearly an over-estimate of the peak value. Is there some condition I can apply to the gaussian fit function?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can define whatever function you want, try to add an offset to your `Gauss` function:

```
def Gauss(velo_peak, a, mu0, sigma, offs):
         res = a * np.exp(-(velo_peak - mu0)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) + offs
         return res
```